# How to get number of years from date range PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date

I have number of dates using the date ranges in date format. Now, I would like to have only years from that date.

Lets say someone, gives the date range `from: 01-01-2010 to 09-05-2019.`

I would like to have only `years` from this date so I will include them in my sql query.

The query is working for only `2015` if specified ranges in this year but how I can have it for all the years only within ranges?

Here is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT
    MONTH (transaction_date),
    SUM(case when finance_type != 'Deposit' then amount else 0 end) AS total_amount,
    SUM(case when finance_type = 'Deposit' then amount else 0 end) AS deposit,
    SUM(case when finance_type != 'Deposit' AND amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) AS expenses,
    SUM(case when finance_type != 'Deposit' AND amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) AS earning,          
    SUM(case when finance_type != 'Deposit' AND amount!='' then num_contract else 0 end) AS total_contracts,
    transaction_date  
      FROM 
        `tbl_finanace`
            WHERE
                transaction_date LIKE '%2015%'
            AND user_id = '15'
                GROUP BY
            MONTH (transaction_date)
                ORDER BY
            MONTH (transaction_date)";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get years between 2 dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892912/get-years-between-2-dates)

Comment: Is `transaction_date` a string/text/blob type in the database? If it is, then you should really change it to either integer or some date/datetime type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use less than and greater than if its a DATETIME field.

```
where transaction_date <= '2010-01-01 00:00:01' and transaction_date >= '2005-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your `LIKE` clause on the date and use

```
WHERE YEAR(transaction_date) 
BETWEEN YEAR('01-01-2010') AND YEAR('09-05-2019')
```