# How do i write code to control two variables making them interdependent

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to limit the Age of a registering participants on a site to 16 years and above using php i have an if statement saying

```
if ($DOBYear === '1999' && $DOBMonth === 'November'|| 'December') {
    echo('You have to be at least 16 years to register');
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as when the months November or December are selected as the `$DOBMonth` values it echoes'You have to be at least 16 years to register'regardless of whether `$DOBYear` is 1999 or not. How can i make both variables interdependent.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1892948/4296515

Comment: You do realize, with this structure, you have to update your code every month? We're programmers to automate things.

Comment: `dob === Nov || Dec` will eval as `dob === (Nov || Dec)` -> `dob === true` -> `false`, causing the entire `if` to fail.

Comment: Daan I'm aware of this. The site is for an annual event. I'm very new to programming so I'll be sure to take this into consideration. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change your check to something like this:

```
if ($DOBYear === '1999' && ($DOBMonth === 'November'|| $DOBMonth === 'December'))
```

So you can be sure that it needs to be that year AND one of those months.

Even better should be to calculate the age, and check that:

```
$ageDt = new DateTime($age);
$nowDt = new DateTime();
$diff = $nowDt->diff($ageDt);
$age = $diff->y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for both combinations separately. Checking for:

- The year 1999 AND the month November

OR

- The year 1999 AND the month December

---

Example :

```
if (($DOBYear === '1999' && $DOBMonth === 'November') || ($DOBYear === '1999' && $DOBMonth === 'December'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// assumes you have a DOBday, otherwise drop this and the j
$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y F j',
    $DOBYear. ' ' . $DOBMonth . ' ' . $DOBday
);
$cutoff = new DateTime();

$cutoff->sub('P16Y'); // take off the 16 years.

if ($cutoff < $dob) {
    echo 'You have to be at least 16 years to register';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your if, try:

```
if ($DOBYear === '1999' && $DOBMonth === 'November' || $DOBYear === '1999' && $DOBMonth === 'December'){
echo('You have to be at least 16 years to register');
}
```

or

```
if ($DOBYear === '1999' && ($DOBMonth === 'November' || $DOBMonth === 'December')){
echo('You have to be at least 16 years to register');
}
```